# Есть задача подсчет автоматического процентного соотношения для каждого блока с svg кольцами (прогресс бар) но скрипт срабатывает только для первого

Tags: javascript, css, progress-bar

```js
var el = document.getElementsByClassName( 'progress-ring' );
if( el.length > 1 ) {
  const circle = document.querySelector('.progress-ring__circle');
  const circumference = 2 * Math.PI * circle.r.baseVal.value;

  function setProgress(){

    circle.style.strokeDasharray = `${circumference} ${circumference}`;
    circle.style.strokeDashoffset = circumference;

    var article = document.querySelector('.progress-ring__circle');
    data = article.dataset;
    const offset = circumference - data.percent / 100 * circumference;
    circle.style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
  }
  
  setProgress();  
}
```

```css
.row_cont_item_stg_title {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #3A3B40;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.row_cont_item_stg_desc {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22.4px;
}
.row_cont_item_svg_cont {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}
```

```html
<svg class="progress-ring" width="58" height="58" >
  <circle class="progress-ring__circle" stroke="#2D4AE5" stroke-width="2" cx="29" cy="29" r="25" fill="transparent" data-percent="15" />
 </svg>

<svg class="progress-ring" width="58" height="58" >
  <circle class="progress-ring__circle" stroke="#2D4AE5" stroke-width="2" cx="29" cy="29" r="25" fill="transparent" data-percent="25" />
</svg>
```

Помогите с реализацией

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот немного упростил ваш код

```js
function setProgress(circle) {
    const circumference = 2 * Math.PI * circle.r.baseVal.value;
    circle.style.strokeDasharray = circumference;
    circle.style.strokeDashoffset = circumference - circle.dataset.percent / 100 * circumference;
}

document.querySelectorAll('.progress-ring__circle').forEach(setProgress);
```

```html
<svg class="progress-ring" width="58" height="58" >
  <circle class="progress-ring__circle" stroke="#2D4AE5" stroke-width="2" cx="29" cy="29" r="25" fill="transparent" data-percent="15" />
 </svg>

<svg class="progress-ring" width="58" height="58" >
  <circle class="progress-ring__circle" stroke="#2D4AE5" stroke-width="2" cx="29" cy="29" r="25" fill="transparent" data-percent="25" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!